# Replacement for DoesUserHavePermissions for List object in SP2013

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working on an app that reuses some code from a previous solution.

The idea is to show a user all of the lists of a certain type in all the webs in a site collection so that the user can aggregate some data.

```
static public List<SPListMeta> AllSiteAnnouncementsLists(ClientContext clientContext)
{
    var returnList = new List<SPListMeta>();
    var per = new BasePermissions();
    per.Set(PermissionKind.Open);
    if (clientContext.Site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(per).Value)
    {
        var rootWebLists = clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Lists;

        returnList.AddRange(from List oList in rootWebLists
                            where oList.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems) &&
                            where oList.BaseTemplate == (int)ListTemplateType.Announcements
                            select new SPListMeta(oList));
        var collWebs =
            clientContext.Site.OpenWebById(clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Id).GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
        foreach(Web oWeb in collWebs)
        {

        }
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

The critical line that does not work and does not seem to have a replacement is

`oList.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems)`

as this has been removed from the CSOM List object

What's the new way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The new way to check for permissions is:

`List.EffectiveBasePermissions.Has(PermissionKind.Open)`